# User name by SID?

Tags: windows, sid

How can I determine user name and domain if all I have is the user's SID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ADFind](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm) can do this. The list of options is [here](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/usage.htm). For example, you might do something like this to export a list of users with their SID:

```
adfind -h domaincontroller01:389 -b "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" -f "(objectClass=user)" objectSID displayName
```

You can run ADFind from any box as long as it can reach a domain controller. Obviously you would replace domaincontroller01 with the name or IP of a domain controller and change the "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" to reflect the path to the users in question.

Answer (score 4):

`psgetsid` from SysInternals [`PSTools`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) will do this. Put a SID on the command line it will give you the user/group name, and visa-versa.

Answer (score 3):

Fire up windows powershell and run:

```
$strSID="S-1-5-21-500000003-1000000000-1000000003-1001"
$uSid = [ADSI]"LDAP://<SID=$strSID>"
echo $uSid
```

the output should look something like this,

```
distinguishedName : {CN=John Doe,OU=Domain Admins,OU=People,OU=xxx,DC=xxx}
Path              : LDAP://<SID=S-1-5-21-500000003-1000000000-1000000003-1001>
```

Comment: 11 years later, and this is still the easiest way to do this without relying on external tools. Output also includes a bunch of other AD attributes that can be selected, including `sAMAccountName` and `userPrincipalName`, either of which would fulfill the asker's original request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open regedit (Windows-R regedit)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
3. Click on the subkeys (something like `S-1-5-19`)
4. Look at the `ProfileImagePath` (it'll have something like `%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\LocalService`).

So in this example SID S-1-5-19 is LocalService

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. e.g. On my machine there's a user entry for S-1-5-21-2052111302-1972579041-1801674531-2121 but there's no way to tell from that who the user is.

Comment: double checking on the system in front of me, it shows the ProfileImagePath pointing at the user directory.  @JohnGardeniers what does the ProfileImagePath subkey say for you?

Comment: given that my comment was made over 2 years ago I'm sure you'll understand that I'm no longer at that machine, or even at that workplace. For that matter, I'm no longer even using the same OS.